# Requests response object: how to check page loaded completely (dynamic content)?

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am doing the following. After creating a session I am doing a simple GET to a page. Problem is, this page if full of dynamic parts, so it takes between 10-30 seconds to fully generate the HTML I am interested in. The HTML I process with BeautifulSoup.

If I process the response object too quickly, I don't get the data I want. I have used "sleep" to pause for some time, but I think there should be a better way to check for complete page load. I cannot depend on status 200 code, because inside the main page, dynamic parts are still loading.

My code:

```
s = requests.session()
r = s.get('URL')
time.sleep(20)
... code to process response object...
```

I have tried to do it more "elegantly" to check for a certain tag through BeautifulSoup search, but doesn't seem to work.

My code:

```
title_found = False
while title_found == False:
        soupje = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
        title_found_in_html_full = soupje.find(id='titleView!1Title')
        if title_found_in_html_full is not None:
            title_found_in_html = title_found_in_html_full.get('id')
            if title_found_in_html == 'titleView!1Title':
                title_found = True
```

Is it true the response object changes over time as the page is loading?

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Ok, it seems the second part of the code works. There where some issues with the web server delivering the page (outages). Still suggestions to do it more pythonic are welcome!

Comment: I believe that you are dealing with `url` which is loaded dynamically with `JavaScript` which `requests` will not be able to render it. use `selenium`